# Inspect popup for debugging chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have downloaded Page redder extension from http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html but when I right click on the icon of this extension ,I do not see inspect popup.This needs to be enabled to debug the extension.Can anyone throw light on what could be the issue?
Thanks

Comment: Chris is right with his answer but this extension doesn't have a popup, so only thing you can debug is a background page.

Answer (score 3):

To enable the `Inspect pop-up` option, you have to enable `Developer mode` on the `chrome://extensions` page.

Comment: I have already done that.I am able to see the option for other extensions except for this one.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the **Inspect popup** option in chrome extension *context menu*,

Insert *default_popup* property under *browser_action* in **manifest.json** of your extension package.

Example: "default_popup": "popup.html"

Ref: [Page Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) and [manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest)